# Dropzone config not working + 'Dropzone already attached' error

Tags: jquery, twig, symfony, dropzone.js, assetic

I'm using dropzone for handling image uploads on the front-end side.
The plugin was working fine as long as it was stored in the **head** portion as a **CDN**.
Lately I tried to download it and add into assetic like so:

```
{% block javascripts %}
    {% javascripts 
        'Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.min.js'
        'Scripts/dropzone.js'
        'Scripts/scripts.js' 
        'Scripts/scripts_admin.js'
    %}
        <script src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
    {% endjavascripts %}
{% endblock %}
```

However since adding it like so I kept getting the error in console saying:

> Uncaught Error: Dropzone already attached

I don't want to add the element programatically so I would prefer not using the `Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;` parameter.

Now also I tried to get loader to have some options and trigger a page refresh when all images are finished loading, but despite using the exact same code used in [working fiddles](http://jsfiddle.net/RenjithVR4/v8a52nan/4/) I still cant get the `console.log()` to work when needed.

Here is the form in html:

```
<form action=" {{ oneup_uploader_endpoint('gallery') }}"  method="post" class="dropzone" id="my-awesome-dropzone">
</form>
```

And here are the options I'm (attempting to be) using

```
jQuery(function($) {

    Dropzone.options.myAwesomeDropzone = {
        maxFilesize: 5,
        addRemoveLinks: true,
        dictResponseError: 'Server not Configured',
        acceptedFiles: ".png,.jpg,.gif,.bmp,.jpeg",
        init: function() {
            this.on("queuecomplete", function(progress) {
                console.log("Uploaded!!!");
            });
        }
    };
//...
```

How can I make this work properly?

Any help would be amazing

Answer (score 5):

**FIXED**: All I had to do was take the parameters out of the `jQuery(function($) {));`